# How does one pipe `rawRequestBody` into `requestBodySource`?

Tags: haskell, yesod, conduit, http-conduit

Yesod has `rawRequestBody` with the following type signature:

```
rawRequestBody :: MonadHandler m => Source m ByteString
```

And http-conduit has this function that converts a source into a `RequestBody`:

```
requestBodySource :: Int64 -> Source (ResourceT IO) ByteString -> RequestBody
```

I want to be able to stream the `rawRequestBody` to an S3 object by converting it into a `RequestBody` *inside a handler*, `ResourceT IO ~ MonadHandler` doesn't compute and I can't seem to do `MonadHandler m => m -> ResourceT IO`

I've tried:

[`transPipe`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-2.18/hoogle?q=transpipe) - if we get `Source Handler ByteString` from `rawRequestBody` it seems like the only way to get at the `ByteString` is to `consume` it, i.e

```
transPipe ??? rawRequestBody :: Source (ResourceT IO) ByteString
```

[`handlerToIO`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-2.18/hoogle?q=handlertoio) - however it seems like the request body is cleared so there won't be any data available

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [waiRequest](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-2.18/yesod-core-1.4.12/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:waiRequest) will give you back the WAI [Request](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-2.18/wai-3.0.3.0/Network-Wai.html#t:Request) value. You can use [sourceRequestBody](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2015-07-15/wai-conduit-3.0.0.2/Network-Wai-Conduit.html) to get a `Source` from that.